# Config file location in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have MySQL 5.5 running in RHEL. I have checked for my.cnf file in my filesystem and its available in two destinations. One in the user's home directory and the other is in /data/etc_ORIG directory. It was not seen in /etc or /etc/mysql folder. Is there any issue with the config file present in a different path? And how do I check which config is being used by MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

As your my.cnf is not on standard location, check 
`ps -ef | grep mysql` for `--defaults-file` option.

Below command will give you default file options:

`mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`

(There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/determine-which-config-file-is-being-used) similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270326/how-to-find-out-the-location-of-currently-used-mysql-configuration-file-in-linux) previously [answered](http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/).)

Comment: ps -ef | grep mysql - doesn't show the --defaults-file for me. It only shows data dir, base dir, plugin dir, user, log error, pid file.

Comment: Try the last blog link anchored to "answered"... it has covered multiple options.

Comment: ok I'm having trouble enabling the binary logging.

Comment: I saw your question for the same. So the answer to it will be dependent on the answer to this one :)
Invited you to a chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following command to check if `my.cnf` is used or note by executing the following command `ps -ef |grep mysql` or `strace ./mysqld` the first command (`ps -ef |grep mysql`) will show you the active mysql service ID and the default `cnf` file location, the other one will show you only the location of the `cnf` file.

As for the location my the `cnf` file it can be anywhere as long as MySQL user can access it and the file has  644 permission level.